# jQuery Scroll up/down animations blocking

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, blocking

I have a problem regarding two animations, one scrolling down and one scrolling up (when the user has scrolled back up completely).
The animations block each other - with the following source code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(window).on("load",function() {
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if($(window).offset().top == 0){
                    $("selector").animate({}, 500);
                    $("selector").animate({}, 500);
                } else {
                    $("selector").animate({}, 500);
                    $("selector").animate({}, 500);
                }
            });
        }).scroll();
    });
```

So it happens that after the true statement block of the if directly the else part is executed again and therefore the animation is partly not executed at all or both are executed one after the other. Does anyone have an idea that the animations are executed reliably:

- else animation once as soon as scrolling down was done
- if-Animation as soon as scrolling up completely again

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your first guess `"selector"` stands for in `$("selector").animate({}, 500);`?

Comment: The selector is working fine. I just removed the full one cause it does not matter for the question. Sorry for confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Makes no sense to cauculate `$(window).offset().top` since... it does what it says. `0`.
Perhaps, on `"scroll"` Event you want to get the  `$(window).scrollTop()`

```js
jQuery($ => {

  const $win = $(window);
  const $items = $(".item");

  $win.on("scroll", () => {
    $items.toggleClass("active", $win.scrollTop() == 0);
  });

  $win.on("load", () => {
    $win.trigger("scroll");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  /* your styles here */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But that's not working how I want. I want a animation A toggled if the user scrolled down and animation B toggled if the user is again at the scrollTop = 0 position.